# How to group data attached to discriminated union values, in F#?

Tags: f#, discriminated-union

Here is an example:

```
type Events =
    | A of AData
    | B of BData
    | C of CData
```

and I have a list of those:

```
let events : Events list = ...
```

I need to build a list by event type. Right now I do this:

```
let listA =
    events
    |> List.map (fun x ->
        match x with
        | A a -> Some a
        | _ -> None
    )
    |> List.choose id
```

and, repeat for each type...

I also thought I could do something like:

```
let rec split events a b c =
    match events with
    | [] -> (a |> List.rev, b |> List.rev, c |> List.rev)
    | h :: t ->
        let a, b, c =            
            match h with
            | A x -> x::a, b, c
            | B x -> a, x::b, c
            | C x -> a, b, x::c
        split t a b c
```

Is there a more elegant manner to solve this?

This processes a lot of data, so speed is important here.

Comment: Maybe List.group

Comment: The `type Events` might be suboptimal for the task at hand. Depends on the scale of refactoring that may be afforded, of course.

Comment: I've run into this issue before. It's one of a few (relatively rare) cases I've noted in F# where you know what you want to do, but the language doesn't offer an elegant way to do it. So I don't have any useful suggestions. Your option B is what I've usually done (it's not too inelegant ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your solution is pretty good, although you do pay a price for reversing the lists. The only other semi-elegant approach I can think of is to unzip a list of tuples:

```ml
let split events =
    let a, b, c =
        events
            |> List.map (function 
                | A n -> Some n, None, None
                | B s -> None, Some s, None
                | C b -> None, None, Some b)
            |> List.unzip3
    let choose list = List.choose id list
    choose a, choose b, choose c
```

This creates several intermediate lists, so careful internal use of `Seq` or `Array` instead might perform better. You would have to benchmark to be sure.

Test case:

```ml
split [
    A 1
    A 2
    B "one"
    B "two"
    C true
    C false
] |> printfn "%A"   // [1; 2],[one; two],[true; false]
```

By the way, your current solution can be simplified to:

```ml
let listA =
    events
    |> List.choose (function A a -> Some a | _ -> None)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can [fold back](https://fsharp.github.io/fsharp-core-docs/reference/fsharp-collections-listmodule.html#foldBack) the list of events to avoid writing a recursive function and reversing results. With an [anonymous record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/anonymous-records) you will need to define it first and then pipe both arguments `||>` to `List.foldBack`:

```
let eventsByType =
    (events, {| listA = []; listB = []; listC = [] |})
    ||> List.foldBack (fun event state ->
        match event with
        | A a -> {| state with listA = a :: state.listA |}
        | B b -> {| state with listB = b :: state.listB |}
        | C c -> {| state with listC = c :: state.listC |})
```

With a named record it is more elegant:

```
 { listA = []; listB = []; listC = [] } |> List.foldBack addEvent events
```

`addEvent` is the same as the lambda above except usage of a named record `{}` instead of `{||}`.

Comment: Yeah, fold and friends are implemented imperatively, so *were at a time* supposed to be more efficient. On the other hand, reversing lists is very idiomatic. I won't be surprised if F# compiler optimizes that, given how much time the compilation takes on my Gen12 CPU… Without (a) performance requirements and (b if a) benchmarking, the preference is just that, a personal preference. I'm not arguing at all, just sharing my thoughts. Missing data on (a) and (a)->(b), I'm torn between the OP's and your solutions,, so I'll upvote both :-)) Oh, BTW, “Thinking...” by Dani Kahneman is da book!!!

Comment: Oh, and anonymous _value_ records shouldn't hurt perf. But... (b->a). Benchmark, benchmark, benchmark — if you have reason for the code to be more performant.

Answer (score 1):

If you keep the union cases, you can group the list items like this.

```
let name = function
    | A _ -> "A"
    | B _ -> "B"
    | C _ -> "C"

let lists =
    events 
    |> List.groupBy name
    |> dict
```

And then you can extract the data you want.

```
let listA = lists["A"] |> List.map (fun (A data) -> data)
```

(The compiler doesn't realize the list only consists of "A" cases, so it gives an incomplete pattern match warning)